# Updated code not running when running my web page with firebase serve

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-tools

I'm having this really weird error with my JavaScript code and Firebase. I will update my JavaScript code in my editor, Atom, save the .js file then go to the place where this file is located in the terminal and run `firebase serve`.

Most of the time this runs fine and my web page runs as intended and the code is the same when I use the 'inspect' function, however sometimes I will have an error which I go to fix, but after I update it in my editor, it will not be updated in the actual web page even after refreshing and re-running firebase serve.

I'll add a simple example just because I might not have explained it very well.

```
var percentage;
```

This is what I have saved in my editor.

```
var percentage:;

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I had initially put the colon in by mistake, but even after I take it out this is what keeps coming up in my web page no matter how many times I refresh or re-run `firebase serve`.

Comment: The Firebase command line tools don't keep a persistent cache between runs. So the only way I can imagine this happening is when the browser is caching the file aggressively. If this happens again: try a different browser to ensure it's not a caching issue.

Comment: Yeah it turned out to be a caching issue. All I had to do to fix it was refresh my cache. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good to hear Haris!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a caching issue. All I had to do to fix it was refresh my cache.